# Bash function to remove duplicates from POSIX PATH

Tags: bash, shell

I needed a function to remove duplicates from my POSIX PATH (and MANPATH, etc.), so I wrote this one.  I'm new to bash, and making a mistake in $PATH is not good.  I know it'll barf on Windows PATH.  Are my quotes OK?  If it were your root shell, what would you change?

```
fixpath() {

    local IFS=:
    local -A alreadyDone
    local -a newpath
    local -i i
    local frag
    i=0

    for frag in $@ ; do
    [ ${alreadyDone[$frag]+abc} ] || {
        alreadyDone[$frag]=$frag;
        newpath[$i]=$frag;
        ((i++))
    }
    done
    printf '%s\n' "${newpath[*]}"
    return 0
}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
-bash-4.4$ fixpath /var/tmp:/home/bennett/bin:/home/bennett/bin:/usr/oneworld/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/home/bennett/bin:/home/bennett/bin:/usr/oneworld/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/tmp:/home/bennett/bin:/home/bennett/bin:/usr/oneworld/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin         

/var/tmp:/home/bennett/bin:/usr/oneworld/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/tmp
```

My concern is spaces and shell meta-chars, and I don't know if I've protected myself.

Also, this relies on `declare -A`.  How would I do this in bash-3?

p.s.  The example is faked up for testing.  I don't really have `/tmp` in my path.  Also, I have little/no control of how it got cocked-up in the first place;  I just want it fixed.

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- you've got a bunch of quoting bugs. (`$@` is absolutely not the same as `"$@"`, even when `IFS` doesn't contain whitespace, and that difference will be crystal clear if you somehow had a literal `*` in your `PATH`).

Comment: Also, if you have a directory that can be interpreted as a glob -- ie. `[foo]`, which can be interpreted as a glob matching `f` or `o` -- leaving out the quotes tells the shell to *attempt* to interpret it in that way (potentially resulting in the element being completely skipped if the `nullglob` shell option is enabled, or a failure if the `failglob` option is set).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/remove-duplicate-path-entries-with-awk-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash 4, I'd implement this as follows:

```
fixpath() {
    local out_str
    local -a pieces=( ) out=( )
    local -A seen=( )

    IFS=: read -a pieces <<<"$1"

    for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do
      [[ ${seen[$piece]} ]] && continue
      out+=( "$piece" )
      seen[$piece]=1
    done

    printf -v out_str '%s:' "${out[@]}"
    printf '%s\n' "${out_str%:}"
}
```

Note:

- All expansions are either quoted, or in a context where string-splitting and glob expansion are explicitly prohibited. Setting `IFS=:` works around some of the most obvious pitfalls of missing quotes, but by no means does it resolve all of them.
- `IFS=: read -r -a` is used to read into an array with `:` explicitly used as a delimiter. This modifies `IFS` only for the single command, having no impact on any other scope (and not depending on `local IFS` to work as-expected; I distinctly recall seeing shells where it doesn't, though I'd need to dig to figure out exactly where that is).
- There's no reason to `return 0`, and doing so is counterproductive. The default return value is the exit status of the last command. If `printf` failed (perhaps because your stdout is to a closed or invalid FD), you *shouldn't* return a successful status.

---

In bash 3, without associative arrays, things get significantly less efficient. Fortunately, a PATH is generally short enough that O(n^2) is not prohibitive (to the point of still being faster than spinning up an external interpreter to do the work in awk or perl):

```
fixpath() {
    local out_str seen
    local -a pieces=( ) out=( )

    IFS=: read -a pieces <<<"$1"

    for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do
      seen=0
      for out_piece in "${out[@]}"; do
        [[ "$out_piece" = "$piece" ]] && { seen=1; break; }
      done
      (( seen )) && continue
      out+=( "$piece" )
    done

    printf -v out_str '%s:' "${out[@]}"
    printf '%s\n' "${out_str%:}"
}
```

Comment: Splendid!  If I were to "merge" these into a bash_3_or_4_fixpath, is it reasonable to test for v4 with the following? declare -A someHash 2> /dev/null || { bash3CodeHere }

Comment: Personally, I use `[[ $BASH_VERSION = [1-3].* ]]` to detect the bash-prior-to-4 case. BTW, you can use an `if` to control which function definition is invoked, and thus only run one of them, rather than making the function pick logic to use at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that was the plan.  I'll have one big `if` to encapsulate all of the bash 3 code, function declarations, etc. vs. bash 4.  I was hoping to have some logic that would test features, rather than version numbers.  Like the `${@Q}` notation, which seems to be a bash 4.4 feature.  I can live with version numbers, though.  I can't seem to find a clever way to test for `${@Q}` without something printing out.

Comment: Easily done. `if  { : "${IFS@Q}"; } 2>/dev/null; then echo "We have @ modifiers on expansions"; else echo "No @ modifiers on expansions"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easier to do with Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $input = shift;
my %seen;

foreach my $dir ( split /:/, $input ) {
        $seen{$dir} = 1;
}
my $output = join( ':', keys(%seen));
print $output . "\n";
```

You won't have to worry about dealing with spaces in the directory names.

```
$ ./fixpath.pl "/var/tmp:/home/bennett/bin:/home/bennett/bin:/usr/oneworld/bin:/usr/local/bin:/path with space/dir:/usr/local/bin"
/var/tmp:/path with space/dir:/home/bennett/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/oneworld/bin
```

If you want to ensure you do not change the order of path's do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $input = shift;
my %seen;

my $order=1;
foreach my $dir ( split /:/, $input ) {
        $seen{$dir} = $order++ unless ($seen{$dir})  ;
}
my $output =  join( ':',  sort { $seen{$a} <=> $seen{$b} } keys(%seen));
print $output . "\n";
```

Comment: Spaces in the directory names weren't a problem with the OP's original code either. Glob expressions were a problem (because they weren't quoting adequately), but an easily-fixed one.

Comment: Yeah, the original code was in perl.  I was hoping to avoid using an external process.  Even though I'm caching the PATH once it's fixed, I'd like it to be sort of efficient.  The target machine is a little slow.  But I think your perl code messes up the order of the path.

Comment: Ah. If you want to preserve  the order of the path you'll need to sort the %seen hash. I've update my answer.

Comment: This still goofs up the path.  Because of the way you assign the order and then sort it, all of the duplicates float to the back of the path.